# Passing data from parent to specific children in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a parent component that dynamically loads child components via `*ngFor`. My parent component loads data for rendering child components. There is extra data needed after on user request.

The html of parent component:

```
<panel *ngFor="let item of collection" (selected)="onTogglePanel($event, item)">
    <div panel-body>
        <item-detail
            *ngIf="item.detail; else templateLoading"
            [detail]="item.detail"
            (eventItemLoad)="getExtraData($event, item.detail)"
            ></item-detail>
    </div>
</panel>
```

Each child component, emits an event to the parent component, that will make an http request for getting the data.

The question is, how can I pass the data to the specific child component?

I have been reading about invoking child method from parent, but I don't know really how to invoke only for specified child.

NOTE: Perhaps my approach of parent getting data and passing to children is not correct and each child should get the data. Any advice for the approach is welcome. Thanks for any help.

Comment: your itemDetail component could have an eventEmitter, the parent subscribe to that event and do the logic. To know which itemDetail sended the request you could add an index at the ngFor and pass it to the single itemDetail

Comment: Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The child should get the data on its own.

It looks like you just need `item.detail` to get the additional data. So if you don't need anything from the parent, just let the child make the http request.

This is about [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) : in Angular you achieve this by creating components, each one serving its specific purpose - and not "messing" with another one if it is not needed.

Comment: I agree with you, my approach is quite complicated and it does not make sense. Thanks.